# Counting hidden table rows using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a a table with a couple of hidden rows. What I want to achieve is having it show a hidden row with each button click, is this possible?

I count the number of table rows using the following

```
var rowCount = parseInt($('#Table tr').length);
```

How do I count hidden table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by others, you can specify hidden elements in your selector with the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector.

```
$("#Table tr:hidden").length; //number of hidden <TR> elements
```

As for showing each one with each sequential click of a button, you could make use of the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector as well:

```
$(".showRow").click(function(){
    $("#Table tr:hidden:first").show();   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J3QdQ/

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
$('#Table tr:hidden').length
```

[**:hidden selector**](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible through : hidden operator

```
$('#Table tr:hidden').length
```